# Alt Attribute Doesn't display in Joomla K2

Tags: html, joomla, seo, k2

I am using an existing Joomla CMS with K2 Plugin to manage different an existing database.
I want to enhance the SEO by adding alt attribute to the images.
Currently, only the main image has alt tag and it is generated by the title of the post. All other additional images in the post do not have alt tags.
I used the HTML editor and manually added the alt tags. After clearing the cache and trying other methods the front end still doesn't display the alt info.

`<img src="path/to/the/images" alt="Trying to get this to show up">`

Answer (score 0):

On my K2 sites, this runs without any problems. I would also not expect that K2 fiddles around with the ALT texts of images embedded in your HTML.

You may want to look for other possible errors. E.g. in case I forget the closing quote, JCE will guess how to correct this error and often guess wrong.